# Why i can't get a right response from server using Curl?

Tags: php, jquery, json, curl

I need to get response from server using curl, but I can't.

The site: https://www.investing.com/holiday-calendar/

I can get that calendar using get request, but I need a list with custom dates.  That mean I should use that `datepicker`. So when I press "`apply`" it sent post request with data I needed to get. (see the screenshots)

**The DatePicker:**

[image]

**A post request with JSON response:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    define('DIR', __DIR__);

    $user_agent = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : 'Traider';
    $cookie = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'init_cookie.txt';
    $f = fopen('init_deb.txt', 'w');
    $ch = curl_init();

    $getUrl = 'https://www.investing.com/holiday-calendar/';
    $postUrl = 'https://www.investing.com/holiday-calendar/Service/getCalendarFilteredData';

    $dateFrom='2017-01-14';
    $dateTo='2017-12-31';
    $limit_from = 0;
    $params = [
        'dateFrom' => $dateFrom,
        'dateTo' => $dateTo,
        'county' => '',
        'limit_from' => $limit_from
    ];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $f);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    fclose($f);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $response;
```

**Step 1.** I sent a get request, save cookies.

**Step 2.**  I sent a post request changing `$getUrl -> $postUrl`. I always get the main page. Why I can't get JSON response?

Answer (score 1):

after a bit of testing, the big secret is that they refuse requests that dont have the `X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest` header attached. attach that (using CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER), and you dont even need a cookie session. i guess its part of some XSS protection scheme.

working example code using hhb_curl from https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php :

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
require_once('hhb_.inc.php');
$hc=new hhb_curl();
$hc->_setComfortableOptions();
$hc->setopt_array(array(
        CURLOPT_POST=>true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>http_build_query(array(
                'dateFrom'=>'2017-01-28',
                'dateTo'=>'2017-01-28',
                'country'=>'',
                'limit_from'=>'0'
        )),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array(
                'X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest'
        )
));
$hc->exec('https://www.investing.com/holiday-calendar/Service/getCalendarFilteredData');
hhb_var_dump($hc->getResponseBody());
```